# Django Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting web-1 | TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my Django project. I have the following config files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY csgo .

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - csgo.env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - csgo.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_HOST=localhost
    volumes:
      - ./db/psql-init/db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I try to `docker-compose up` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
csgo-web-1    |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
csgo-web-1    |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
csgo-web-1    | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
csgo-web-1    |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
csgo-web-1    |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What could be the problem? Can you explain what it means by **Is the server running on host "localhost"** and why it wouldn't accept connection on port 5432?

Ports available:

```
com.docke 14554 user  149u  IPv6 0xd0180dc2abc35a25      0t0    TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker typically refers to the current container, so the Django server is reporting that the Django container isn't running a database.  Try using the Compose service name `db` as the database host name instead.

Comment: (You will also have a problem connecting to the container once it's up and running; you need to change the `CMD` to run `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` with the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address as the listen address.  If it's 127.0.0.1 it will be unreachable from outside its own container.)